# Is this a safe/correct way to make a python LogHandler asynchronous?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, asynchronous, python-2.x

I'm using some slow-ish emit() methods in Python (2.7) logging (email, http POST, etc.) and having them done synchronously in the calling thread is delaying web requests.  I put together this function to take an existing handler and make it asynchronous, but I'm new to python and want to make sure my assumptions about object scope are correct.  Here's the code:

```
def patchAsyncEmit(handler):                                                     
    base_emit = handler.emit                                                     
    queue = Queue.Queue()                                                        
    def loop():                                                                  
        while True:                                                              
            record = queue.get(True) # blocks                                    
            try :                                                                
                base_emit(record)                         
            except: # not much you can do when your logger is broken                                                           
                print sys.exc_info()                                      
    thread = threading.Thread(target=loop)                                       
    thread.daemon = True                                                         
    thread.start()                                                               
    def asyncEmit(record):                                                       
        queue.put(record)                                                        
    handler.emit = asyncEmit                                                     
    return handler
```

That let's me create an asynchronous LogHandler using code like:

```
handler = patchAsyncEmit(logging.handlers.HttpHandler(...))
```

I've confirmed the messages are sent, and not in the calling thread, but I want to make sure I'm getting only one queue and only one thread per Handler, and that I'm not at risk of those somehow going out of scope.

Am I off base or did I get that okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem to me that writing a class would be better:

```
class AsyncHandler(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, handler):
         self._handler = handler
         self._queue = Queue.Queue()

         self.daemon = True
         self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
           record = self._queue.get(True)
           self._handler.emit(record)

    def emit(self, record):
        self._queue.put(record)
```

Patching objects can be useful, but its usually clearer to create another object like this.

Comment: A decorator like that (the pattern not the @pythonthing) is the route I wanted to go, but the LogHandler creation, at least when using the dictionary schema http://docs.python.org/library/logging.config.html#configuration-dictionary-schema ), doesn't allow for passing a handler into a handler's constructor -- only literals.  So I couldn't think of a way to make that work using dict config (which I recognize I didn't mention in the question), but if there is a way I'd welcome it.

Comment: @Ry4an, ah. Actually, I believe you can pass objects using the cfg:// syntax.

Comment: oh, wow, I hadn't previously seen that at all.

Comment: A LogHandler has a few other important methods (configuration, etc.) would all of those have to be written into the AsyncHander to delegate correctly to the `_handler`?  Is there an easy way to pull in all of `_handler`'s method except the one we want to override?

Comment: @Ry4an, in that case I'd probably want to subclass the handler of interest.

Comment: But if I want an asynchronous wrapper for the python standard HTTPLogHandler, SocketHandler, and SMTPHandler do I need to put the async code in a subclass of each of them?  I did end up subclassing them but then had the __init__ method of each subclass call my original `patchAsychEmit` with `self` as an argument.  I see python provides BufferingHandler and MemoryHandler which are decorators w/ a target of the sort you did, so that's probably the right way even if it does mean wrapping some extra methods.  Thanks!

Comment: @Ry4an, with a little multiple inheritance you should be able to avoid putting the async code in multiple classes or doing the patching. Whether thats better then the extra method wrapping is hard to say. You could also overload __getattr__, but that quickly gets messy so I can't recommend it

Comment: Yeah, I tried pulling all the attributes of the "target" into the client automatically and that quickly went past the depth of my meager python knowledge.  I'll stick with the patch for now, but it makes sense that a class is the way to go and multiple inheritance is the way to do it.  In Scala I'd be using a trait, which is multiple inheritance without the horror.  Thanks a ton.